# Python subprocess.Popen stdout adds spaces and corrupts term

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, output, stdout

Okay, so. I'm writing a very basic Python script that just takes the output from a df -h and shows it on the screen. I'm going to implement some other functionality but this part is leaving me stumped.

I'm pretty sure my code is correct, I've even put in time.sleep() statements to see if maybe the output was going too quickly. But when I iterate through stdout, even with rstrip(), the terminal output is spaced oddly every time a new line is created and it corrupts the terminal.

Anythoughts?

Here's my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import re
import subprocess
import time

np1=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
np2=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p4=subprocess.Popen('ssh -qt <redacted>/usr/bin/sudo df -h /opt/saswork', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


for x in np1.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid NP01 is at ", str(y)
time.sleep(1)
for x in np2.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid NP02 is at ", str(y)
time.sleep(1)
for x in p1.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid P01 is at ", str(y)
time.sleep(1)
for x in p2.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid P02 is at ", str(y)
time.sleep(1)
for x in p3.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid P03 is at ", str(y)
time.sleep(1)
for x in p4.stdout:
    x=x.rstrip()
    x=re.findall('.\d%', x)
    for y in x:
        print "SAS Grid P04 is at ", str(y)
```

Here's the output

```
SAS Grid NP01 is at  33%
                    SAS Grid NP02 is at  36%
                                            SAS Grid P01 is at   3%
                                                                   SAS Grid P02 is at  23%
                                                                                          SAS Grid P03 is at  41%
                                                                                                                 SAS Grid P04 is at  24%
                                                                                                                                        [<service account>@werindgatep01 ~]$
                                                                                                                                                                 [<service account>@werindgatep01 ~]$
```

What I have to do at this point is CTRL-C and CTRL-D until it drops me out of the service account and back to my standard user account. From there I can sudo su - service account

I'm lost . . .quite lost

Comment: Before you ask your next question, please read [ask] and, more specifically, [mcve]. Reducing the size of your example program and getting rid of extraneous elements will improve the quality of the responses you receive.

Comment: What OS are you using? If it is Linux, what distribution and version?

Comment: The `print` statement is what adds spaces between what it prints. For every time in the comma-separated list you give it it will insert a space. For better control of that use the function form, or just use `sys.stdout.write()` method.

Comment: What happens if you add `print "abc"; print "def\r"; print "gh"` after `Popen()`?

Comment: I am facing the similar issue, were you able to fix this?

Comment: I was able to fix this by passing "stdin=subprocess.PIPE" to subprocess.Popen and requesting psuedo-terminal via -t for ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the dot in your `.findall()` regex is picking up a tab character. Try checking for and removing that...?

Answer (score 0):

The `-t` switch to `ssh` is forcing your terminal into raw mode. Raw mode defeats the implicit carriage return at the end of lines, and messes up your text input.

From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh): "*[-t] can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.*"

Since you aren't running a visual editor or other screen-based program, I suggest you lose the `-t`.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The `-t` switch simply forces opening and using a pty, rather than switching to pipes when a command is given. The app is what sets the mode.

Comment: That's . . .surprising. I won't lie, I didn't think this would work but I just gave it a shot and it seems to be holding up. I'll continue developing this script and if it holds out, you will have solved a mystery that took the little bit of hair I had left!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but fixed it by adding the "-T" option to the SSH command.

-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.